# Variance analysis for state dependent mixture importance sampling estimators

Tags: variance, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, mixture-distribution

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $k\in\mathbb N$
- $q_i:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int q_i\:{\rm d}\lambda=1$$ and $\nu_i:=q_i\lambda$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$
- $w_1,\ldots,w_k:E\to[0,1]$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\sum_{i=1}^k\int w_i\:{\rm d}\nu_i=1\tag1$$

By $(1)$, $$\nu:=\sum_{i=1}^kw_t\nu_t=\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^kw_iq_i}_{=:\:q}\lambda$$ is a probability measure. Now let

- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda=1$$ and $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $n\in\mathbb N$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\nu$ and $$\tilde I:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{pf}q(X_i)$$

> $\tilde I$ is an ordinary importance sampling estimator$^1$ of $$I:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu.$$ In the context of multiple importance sampling, a nearly optimal (with respect to the variance of the estimator) choice of the weights is given by the balance heuristic. Are there similar results known for the estimator $\tilde I$ described here?

---

$^1$ Note that if the $w_i$ are "state independent", then $(1)$ reduces to $$1=\sum_{i=1}^kw_i\underbrace{\int q_i\:{\rm d}\lambda}_{=\:1}=\sum_{i=1}^kw_i\tag3$$ and hence $\nu$ is an ordinary mixture distribution.